# Search contents of multiple pdf files and return the pdf's file name and matching content?

Tags: bash, unix, pdf, find, pdftotext

I tried this:

```
PDF=$(find /"$DIRECTORY"/ -name '*.pdf' -exec pdftotext {} - \; | grep 'palindrom')
```

in this way `echo "$PDF` prints only some text from the .pdf file in which was found my word "palindrom", but I also want to know the .pdf file name in which he found the word.

In `/"$DIRECTORY"/` there are many folders, .pdf and .txt files so I need to return only the .pdf files whose text conversion matches my word "palindrom"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with the below command? Instead of 'bash' may be 'sh' could help.

```
find "$DIRECTORY" -name \*.pdf | xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo {}; less {} | grep palindrom'
```

Answer (score 0):

Would `find "$DIRECTORY" -name "*.pdf" -exec grep "palindrom"`pdftotext "{}"`\; -print` work?

Edit: it didn't like my back-tick: pdftotext "{}" should be `pdftotext "{}"`

Comment: it says: "find: missing argument for "-exec"

Comment: I'm not by my computer but what command did you end up typing? I know it formated my suggestion weird.